# Как в трехколоночном меню вывести изображение в третьей колонке при наведении на ссылку в первой

Tags: css

Пытаюсь сделать меню в 3 колонки. В 3-ей колонке выводить изображение при наведении на ссылку в первой колонке. Пока смог сделать только с использованием стилей. Но изображение крепится к блоку с ссылкой, а мне нужно в определенном месте ее закрепить. Нашел только, что с помощью background-image можно. Помогите разобраться, спасибо!

```
#menu {
    list-style:none;
    width:700px;
    height:57px;
    margin:30px auto 30px auto;
    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;
    background: #014464;
}

#menu li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    padding: 4px 10px 40px 10px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:16px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    border:none;
}

ul#menu li a{    
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

#menu li a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px; 
    color: #EEEEEE;
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

.drop{
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
    width:710px;
    height:auto; /* 170px */
    margin:30px 0 30px 0;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 30px;
    background:#ccc;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px; 
    color: #EEEEEE;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    text-align: left;
}

li:hover .drop {
    left:-20px;top:11px;
}

.col_1, .col_2, .col_3{
    display:inline;
    float: top;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.col_1 {
    width:231px;
}
.col_2 {
    width:462px;
}
.col_3 {
    width:693px;
}

#menu .drop a:hover img{
    position:absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    left:0px;
}

.col_1 a img{
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <title>Мега меню 3-колонки</title>
</head>

<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" >Двери</a>
        <div class="drop"><p>Быстрый поиск</p>

            <div class="col_1"><a href="#" >Межкомнатные<img src="/newmenu/menu_windows_salamander.jpg" width="154" height="198"></a></div>
            <div class="col_1"><a href="#" >Входные<img src="/newmenu/menu_windows_salamander.jpg" width="154" height="198"></a></div>
            <div class="col_1"><a href="#" >Из ПВХ профиля<img src="/newmenu/menu_windows_salamander.jpg" width="154" height="198"></a></div>
            <div class="col_1"><a href="#" >Из алюминиевого профиля<img src="/newmenu/menu_windows_salamander.jpg" width="154" height="198"></a></div>
            <div class="col_1"><p>Это контент во второй колонке</p></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Портфолио</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

`http://jsfiddle.net/5rpJN/61/

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что у Вас для блока с классом `.col_1` установлено свойство `position: relative`, а это означает, что все внутренние элементы будут позиционироваться относительно этого блока, т.е. стиль

```css
#menu .drop a:hover img{
    position:absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right; /* это свойство будет проигнорировано */
    left:0px;
}
```

установит изображение по левому краю ссылки (подробнее можно почитать здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Попробуйте так (замените соответствующие блоки в таблице стилей):

```css
.col_1, .col_2, .col_3 {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    /* здесь удаляем св-во position, чтобы изображение позиционировалось относительно другого ближайшего родительского элемента со св-ом position, т.е. в Вашем случаем относительно div.drop */
}
.col_1 a img {
    display: none;
    /* по-умолчанию изображение скрыто, а его позиционирование можно задать уже при отображении, т.е. когда пользователь навел курсор на ссылку */
}
#menu .drop a:hover img {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 40px;
    right: 20px;
    /* здесь задаем позицию изображения, причем все изображения будут показаны в одном и том же месте, т.к. позиционируются относительно одного и того же блока*/
}
```